# Does "located outside a rod" make sense?

Tags: prepositions

> The solid rod is located in the hollow tube.

I am trying to rewrite this such that the hollow tube is the subject. My example is as follow:

> The hollow tube is located outside the solid rod.

I am not sure that this sounds natural because the rod has no space inside.

Comment: Without some technical data, I think it is best that you don't use the second example. While *in/inside* is finite, *outside* is not. Since most everything is "outside the solid rod", it isn't descriptive at all. Maybe *surrounds* or *covers*?

Comment: I agree with @user3169 that *outside* is a poor choice of word here. Depending on the exact situation, you could say that the tube surrounds/fits around/encloses/encases/holds the rod.

Comment: Thank for letting me a lot of alternative expressions. I will use "surround" or "enclose" in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, outside does not convey what you are trying to say. Outside here means that it is not inside. It could be anywhere outside: across the room, across the country, etc. Something like

> The hollow tube holds the solid rod.

which would indicate that the rod is stored inside the tube, or

> The hollow tube contains the solid rod.

which would indicate that the rod is inside the tube.

Your use of "located" is offputting to me - for your first sentence, I would usually say

> The solid rod is inside the hollow tube.

in casual speech. However, if this is from technical documentation (it sounds like it is) I would keep it the way you have it.